# SQL I have two table which join with foreign key . I want to find out missing id from second table

Tags: mysql

This two table are join with foreign key. I insert some value in info but i need to find out which value are not inserted into info from name table. 
I mean find name.id is not equal info.sid

[image]

[image]

Comment: current results? expected results?

Comment: This should just be a simple join, LEFT or RIGHT and in there WHERE specify where the ID IS NULL (no match). Post some data and expected results (as opposed to images) if you want answers with any detail. Also, which database engine are you using? SQL-Server and MySQL are different things

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normative approach is an *anti-join* pattern.

To find rows in table1 which have an value in the `id` column which does not have a matching row in table2 (i.e. there are no rows in table2 with `fk_id` value that match)

```
 SELECT t1.id
   FROM table1 t1
   LEFT
   JOIN table2 t2
     ON t2.fk_id = t1.id
  WHERE t2.fk_id IS NULL
```

This query basically says return all rows from table1, along with any matching rows from table2, but *exclude* rows where we found a matching row in table2. Leaving us with only rows from table1 that didn't have a match in table2.

This is a demonstration of just one of the approaches. There are a couple of other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.